# Iterating two lists; then comparing/appending results in an array

Tags: python

I have two lists.

One list of dictionaries.
Another list but with pure strings(I parse it so extract dictionary matching keys)

For example:

List of dictionaries looks like this:

```
list1 = [{'name':'foo', 'age':'12'},{'name':'bar','age':'12'},{'name':'alex','age':13}]
```

Then I have second list looking like this

```
filters_list = ['name=foo', 'age=12']
```

I want to iterate through the first list; then create an empty list then append every matching items.

In this case;

I would get all the names 'foo' and age '13' So this would return me 2 items from the first list aka list1

This is my attempt so far

```
            for items in list1: # main array of dictionaries

                    for filters in filters_list: #second array with payloat formatted string.
                        keys = filters.split('=')[0]
                        values = filters.split('=')[-1]
                        if str(values.strip()) == str(items[keys].replace('$','')):

                             outputArr.append(items)
            return outputArr
```

This is not working correctly.

Comment: Please go over [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and  provide 
your code as [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You code currently can not be pasted/copied into my IDE to check it. It lacks  f.e. the function definiton and propbably other stuff. thanks. Also add "Expected output" and what you get and whats wrong with it., Thanks again.

Comment: Is you expected output a list of dictionaries or strings?  (Please don't use the word "array" in python when you mean "list",  a python array is different to a list).

Comment: I'm talking about list. I want to return dictionaries from list1 aka it is named arr

Comment: @cdarke. What are the difference between array and list. Don't they work the same?

Comment: @Dilli `numpy` arrays are different than python lists. Though you haven't included `numpy` anywhere, are widely used and it's better to avoid confusion by using `list`. I don't think array word is used anywhere for python lists (at least in good resources).

Comment: As well as numpy arrays there is an `array` module in the standard library which has objects that behave more like C arrays (fixed length but efficient).  https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html

Comment: @Dilli Please show your correct output. Also why do you say you want age `13` when your filter says `12`

Comment: Please separate the  parsing, comparison and matching logic to separate functions. It will be so much easier for you. Good luck.

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> arr = [{'name':'foo', 'age':'12'},{'name':'bar','age':'12'},{'name':'alex','age':13}]
>>> filters_arr = ['name=foo', 'age=12']
>>> filters_tuples = [f.split('=') for f in filters_arr]
>>> [item for item in arr if any(item[k] == v for k, v in filters_tuples)]
[{'name': 'foo', 'age': '12'}, {'name': 'bar', 'age': '12'}]
```

Or if you wanted to match `all` filters then:

```
>>> [item for item in arr if all(item[k] == v for k, v in filters_tuples)]
[{'name': 'foo', 'age': '12'}]
```

Comment: Hello! Your solution worked, however I might have age as integer value and not solely string. When I do; it returns me entire list. Weirdly.

Comment: @Dilli It really depends on your `arr` and `filters_arr` to understand why

Answer (score 0):

Here is an straightforward and simple code which works fine:

```
list1 = [{'name':'foo', 'age':'12'},{'name':'bar','age':'12'},{'name':'alex','age':13}]
filters_list = ['name=foo', 'age=12']
output = list()
for dic in list1:
    should_be_added = False
    for filter_ in filters_list:
        key = filter_.split('=')[0]
        value = filter_.split('=')[-1]
        if dic[key] == value:
            should_be_added = True
    if should_be_added:
        output.append(dic)

print(output)
```

Comment: In PEP8 it says "Use one leading underscore only for non-public methods and instance variables." so you should change `_filter` to another name eg. `filter_`